# require_once returns true instead of expected object

Tags: php, composer-php, require, require-once

Both `vendor/autoload.php` files are basically identical:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInit1e055ec2de42b90d5e1653b608643281::getLoader();
```

In both files:

```
$composer_object = ComposerAutoloaderInit1e055ec2de42b90d5e1653b608643281::getLoader();
var_dump($composer_object);
> object(Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader
```

This has had me digging into Composer's autoload files (which has been insightful), but I'm still perplexed:

```
$var = require_once '/srv/path_to_main/vendor/autoload.php';
var_dump($var);
> boolean true

$var = require_once '/srv/path_to_subdir/vendor/autoload.php';
var_dump($var);
> object(Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader
```

Why does requiring the first file return `boolean true`, and not `object(Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader`?

## Update

I created a copy of `vendor/autoload.php`, `vendor/aught.php` and when I require that one, it returns the object.

Comment: I think what gets returned by require / include is what is returned from the file it is requiring / including.  I believe you are getting true because the autoloader you are including does not specify a return.  IE true on success / false, error on failure.  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php#example-128

Comment: Thanks, @AlexBarker. That is my understanding as well. But the specified autoloader _does_ return the object. And check my update, when I duplicate the file and require that one, it does return the expected object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require_once` returns `true` instead of the return value if the file has already been included or required.

You'll find you get `true` for the subdir one as well if you require it twice:

```
require_once '/srv/path_to_subdir/vendor/autoload.php';
$var = require_once '/srv/path_to_subdir/vendor/autoload.php';
var_dump( $var )
```